# What should my $DISPLAY variable be and why is it not set?

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, xorg

I am using Mac OS X `10.10.2` Yosemite and SSHing into a remote machine but cannot get X11 forwarding to work. When I `ssh -X RemoteMachine`, I get :

```sh
$ echo "$DISPLAY"

$
```

to return nothing. Indeed, when I am logged in to my local MacBook and `echo $DISPLAY`, I also get nothing. When, however, I log in to `OtherMachine` via NX and `echo $DISPLAY` it gives me `:1001`. Then, when I `ssh -X RemoteMachine` (from `OtherMachine`), I am able to `echo $DISPLAY` and get a return value of `localhost:12.0` - so I suspect the reason that I cannot get a `$DISPLAY` from my mac is that I don't have a `$DISPLAY` set on my mac.

So ... why don't I have a `$DISPLAY` environment variable set on my mac and how should I go about setting it so that I can correctly get X11 forwarding?

Answer (score 9):

To get X you need to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/)

If you already have XQuartz you need to ssh to your remote machine from an XQuartz xterm.

Comment: You can use Terminal or [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com) as well, both will reflect the `DISPLAY` environment variable set by XQuartz.